# Renaming multiple levels - change "man", "Male", "M" into "male" in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I'm handling a dataset which contains a gender column with messy data. I'd like to change "man", "Male", "M" and "MALE" all into "male".

Is there a convenient way to do this such as grouping them together and assign them the same new name "male"? I tried several packages but none of them could assign one new name to multiple old names.

Thank you so much!! This is the final project of my first semester :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
gender<-c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE", "female", "f", "F", "women")
df<-data.frame(gender)
```

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    new_gender = ifelse(gender %in% c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE"), "men", "women") 
  )
```

You get:

```
 gender new_gender
1    man        men
2   Male        men
3      M        men
4   MALE        men
5 female      women
6      f      women
7      F      women
8  women      women
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case_when in dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(gender = sample(c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE", "woman", "F", "female", NA), 100, replace=TRUE))

df %>% 
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    as.character(gender) %in% c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE") ~ "male",
    as.character(gender) %in% c("woman", "Female", "F", "FEMALE") ~ "female",
    TRUE ~ as.character(gender)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `in%` to change the `levels` of the columns (assuming that it is a `factor` column

```
levels(df1$col)[levels(df1$col) %in% c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE")] <- "male"
```

---

If the column is just `character` class

```
 df1$col[df1$col %%in% c("man", "Male", "M", "MALE")] <- "male"
```

---

Also, if we want to use `tidyverse`, an option is `fct_collapse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df1 %>%
    mutate(col = fct_collapse(col, male = c("Man", "Male", "M", "MALE")))
```

Using a reproducible example with the inbuilt dataset ('iris')

```
data(iris)
iris %>% 
       mutate(Species = fct_collapse(Species, new = c("virginica", "versicolor")))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Problem solved. Yes it is a factor column :)